# Print dyanmic json data in table form using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

So i'm trying to print this json array of object which are tbl_matchScore using javascript to get data in terminal

```
 "tbl_MatchScore": [
                      {
                        "pk_matchScoreID": 15,
                        "fk_matchID": 133137,
                        "fk_teamID": 54438,
                        "inning": 2,
                        "inningStartTime": "",
                        "inningEndTime": "",
                        "oversPlayed": "0",
                        "revisedTarget": 0,
                        "revisedOvers": "",
                        "createdDate": "",
                        "modifiedDate": "",
                        "isAllOut": 0
                      },
                      {
                        "pk_matchScoreID": 16,
                        "fk_matchID": 133137,
                        "fk_teamID": 141065,
                        "inning": 1,
                        "totalRun": 152,
                        "totalWicket": 6,
                        "totalExtra": 10,
                        "penaltyRun": 0,
                        "leadBy": 0,
                        "trailBy": 0,
                        "inningStartTime": "2018-08-18T02:17:15+0000",
                        "inningEndTime": "2018-08-18T03:50:36+0000"
                       ]
                    };
```

I tried using a for loop

```
for (var key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key + " -> " + data[key]);
    }
}
```

I have several similar array of an object which I want to print dynamically.

Comment: `console.log` might be what you are looking for.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: just  `console.log(data[key])` . It should do your work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with [console.table()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/table):

```
> console.table(["apples", "oranges", "bananas"]);
┌─────────┬───────────┐
│ (index) │  Values   │
├─────────┼───────────┤
│    0    │ 'apples'  │
│    1    │ 'oranges' │
│    2    │ 'bananas' │
└─────────┴───────────┘
```

It works with arrays or objects, and you can even select the columns you want to show (as opposed to *all*)

Using your own object (which I called "a"):

```
> console.table(a, ["inningStartTime", "oversPlayed"])
┌─────────┬────────────────────────────┬─────────────┐
│ (index) │      inningStartTime       │ oversPlayed │
├─────────┼────────────────────────────┼─────────────┤
│    0    │             ''             │     '0'     │
│    1    │ '2018-08-18T02:17:15+0000' │             │
└─────────┴────────────────────────────┴─────────────┘
```

EDIT: adding another example with an array of objects to show they are printed correctly:

```
> myArray = [{column1: 'A', column2: 'B'}, {column1: 'C', column2: 'D'}, {column1: 'E', column2: 'F'}]
[
  { column1: 'A', column2: 'B' },
  { column1: 'C', column2: 'D' },
  { column1: 'E', column2: 'F' }
]
> console.table(myArray)
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ (index) │ column1 │ column2 │
├─────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│    0    │   'A'   │   'B'   │
│    1    │   'C'   │   'D'   │
│    2    │   'E'   │   'F'   │
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23537873)

Comment: Thanks @Qeole, I'll elaborate a bit more

Comment: ok so I did try it but thing it I'm getiing same object print multiple times in my console, whic I want only one, I don't know why this is not happening

Comment: @codenoobie are you sure the object is not duplicated in your array? can you show a small example where `console.table` duplicates the output?

Comment: So thing is, it's printing the table no.of.objects in the array times, so for example if array has 5 objects then it will print the same table data 5 times

Comment: yep, you don't need the foreach, just print the data:
```
console.table(data);
```